# Expected value $\mathbb{E}[X-Y \mid X>Y, Y< c]$ for independent variables $X,Y$?

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am looking for the expected value $\mathbb{E}[X-Y \mid X>Y, Y< c]$ for independent variables $X \sim U(x_1, x_2),Y \sim U(y_1,y_2)$, $c\in [y_1, y_2]$?

Is the following formula correct?

$$\mathbb{E}[X-Y \mid X>Y, Y< c] = \frac{\int_{y_1}^{c} \int_{y}^{x_2} (x-y)\frac{1}{(x_2-x_1)(y_2-y_1)} dx dy}{\frac{c-y_1}{y_2-y_1}}$$

Thanks!